# Haskell parsing error on ‘|’ symbol with WinGHCi

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and getting this infamous error.

I have already consulted these links :
[Haskell: parse error on input `|'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309616/haskell-parse-error-on-input) [Haskell parse error on input '|'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057438/haskell-parse-error-on-input) [Haskell - parse error on input `|'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712506/haskell-parse-error-on-input) [Why complains Haskell parse error on input `|' in this Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918779/why-complains-haskell-parse-error-on-input-in-this-function) [Haskell parse error on input `|'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381874/haskell-parse-error-on-input)

What really surprises me is that I copied **exactly** the code that my university teacher gave us in class:

```
data TreeInt = Leaf Int
             | Node TreeInt Int TreeInt
foo :: TreeInt -> Int
foo arg =
 case arg of
  | Leaf x = x
  | Node tLeft x tRight = x
```

I know the problem is below foo arg because the following code compiles :

```
data TreeInt = Leaf Int 
             | Node TreeInt Int TreeInt
foo :: TreeInt -> Int
foo arg = undefined
```

The exact error is : `hw.hs:6:4: error: parse error on input ‘|’`
which makes me believe it is on the 6th line (| Leaf).

What I've tried :

- Transform the code using pattern match (got another error)
- Put the case on the same line as foo arg
- Add more/less spaces
- Adding "let" since some versions of GHC have issues without it (no change)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this (#1):

```
case arg of
  | Leaf x = x
  | Node tLeft x tRight = x
```

You want this (#2):

```
case arg of
  Leaf x -> x
  Node tLeft x tRight -> x
```

The style of #1 is used in other ML-family languages, e.g., OCaml:

```
match arg with
  | Leaf x -> x
  | Node (tLeft, x, tRight) -> x
```

But Haskell uses the “layout rule” to desugar #2 into the following:

```
case arg of {
  Leaf x -> x;
  Node tLeft x tRight -> x;
}
```

(And in fact you can write that explicitly if you prefer.)

Note also that you use `->` with `case` expressions and `=` with definitions:

```
foo arg =
  case arg of
    Leaf x -> x
    Node tLeft x tRight -> x

foo' (Leaf x) = x
foo' (Node tLeft x tRight) = x
```

This is true even if there’s a guard expression on a pattern—which is what the vertical bar (`|`) is actually used for:

```
foo arg =
  case arg of
    Leaf x
      | x < 0 -> 0
      | otherwise -> x
    Node tLeft x tRight
      | x < 0 -> 0
      | otherwise -> x

foo' (Leaf x)
  | x < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = x
foo' (Node tLeft x tRight)
  | x < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = x
```